# How to implement WebSocketContainer into StandardWebSocketClient class

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket

I am attempting to connect to a SockJs web sockets server via [Spring 4.2 WebsocketClient support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client). This is my client so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());

    String url = "ws://localhost:8080/priceticker/ws";
    StompSessionHandler handler = new WSClient() ;
    stompClient.connect(url, handler);
}
```

this will provide the connection I need to subscribe to my channel. 
When I run the code, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:73)
at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.<init>(StandardWebSocketClient.java:76)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I understand I need to provide a WebSocketContainer to the project in the META-INF folder, as instructed by the comments on the failing method:

```
* Obtain a new instance of a WebSocketContainer. The method looks for the
* ContainerProvider implementation class in the order listed in the META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider 
* file, returning the WebSocketContainer implementation from the ContainerProvider implementation
```

But I do not understand how to wire a file into the constructor without any arguments. I have attempted to follow the examples in this [test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket/server/WebSocketServerTests.java) but without any luck. I just need to understand what exactly the container is and how to implement it into my project

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javax websocket only provides specification. It does not provide the implementation. To get full implementation you can use [tyrus-standalone client](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/tyrus/bundles/tyrus-standalone-client/1.9/).

If you are using Maven, add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
     <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks. This is what I have been trying to achieve. I have added the dependancy to my classpath, but it is still throwing the exception. Do i need to extend a class and override or pass the Container class into the method somehow?

Comment: @a.hrdie you don't need to, are you getting the same exception?

Comment: yes, the same exception. I think I have misunderstood the configuration of the client. Should this project be contained in a web servlet ?

Comment: @a.hrdie can you check if your downloaded jar has full class name in `META-INF/services/javax.websocket.ContainerProvider`?

Comment: i added the maven dependancy and was receiving the same error. i have now downloaded org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles » websocket-ri-bundle and added to the classpath and it is working! Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue, added the dependency and still have the same error. Could you detail a bit more how you fixed it @a.hrdie? I don't really understand what you did there. I added the library called websocket-ri-bundle and it's not fixed: https://i.imgur.com/NEzozxi.png